# create a new string with only the odd indexes of string

Tags: python, string, loops, iteration

I have to do the following thing"

**Write a function that takes a string as input and returns a string composed of only the odd indexes of the string. Note: enumerate() is not available.**

now the code I can come up with is

```
def odd_string(data):
    result = ""
    for i in (data):
    return data[0],data[2],data[4]

print (odd_string("hello"))
```

how do i actually append these values to a string and how do I make it so that each odd number will be added(without having to write them all out)

Comment: I suppose you're not allowed to use stride indexing, either?

Comment: That is a bafflingly obtuse assignment. I mean, a string of length `n` has `n//2` odd indices, so you could just do `''.join(map(str, range(1, len(s), 2)))`. That would give you a string composed of the _indices_. Surely that's not what the question means, but it is what it asked for.

Answer (score 7):

Stride indexing (you're probably familiar with it from `range()`) works well here.

```
def odd_string(data):
    return data[1::2]
```

Comment: My guess is that his attempted code is a misinterpretation of the assignment - `0`, `2`, and `4` are clearly not odd indices.

Comment: I originally posted an answer, and then realized that I posted this one almost word for word (I hadn't read it yet). ["There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) :-D  One comment:  The OP said that he needed the **odd** indices, but his example showed the **even** indices (0, 2, 4).  If he really does need the even (not odd), the `return` statement should be `return data[::2]`.

Comment: Ah - much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
def odd_string(data):
result = ''
for c in range(0, len(data)):
    if (c % 2 == 1):
        result += data[c] 
return result
```

Comment: you used the opposite definition of _odd_ from OP. I'm would have picked `%2==1` as well, but the assignment itself needs clarification.

Comment: By the way, you can replace `(c % 2 == 1)` with `c%2`, as a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```
newlist = list(range(10))
print newlist[1::2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while i<T:
temp =input()
even=""
odd=""
j=0
k=1
while j<len(temp):
    even = even+temp[j]
    j+=2
while k<len(temp):
    odd = odd+temp[k]
    k+=2
i+=1
print (even,odd)
```

Comment: This is very inefficient compared to stride. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for letting me know. I tried that, but eventually, it was giving me the even numbers. I did not bother to play around with it and also missed the comment section at stride's answer. So much to learn in python :)